# Similar onBackPressed() for Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello my Android application is using fragments. I am wondering if there is a way I can use the idea of the `onBackPressed()` method in my app with fragments. I have previous and next buttons, but as of now I am just creating new fragments and replacing, and none of the data gets saved. Is there a way to save my data/go back once I have gone forward?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of `Fragment` is different of `Activity`.

One `Activity` could have a many `Fragments`, read that:

> A [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You
>   can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has
>   its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can
>   add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub
>   activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

See more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

---

**SOLUCTION**

So if you wanna handle the onBackPressed behavior in you Fragment you could do that:

```
package com.example.stackoverflowsandbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // your code here...
        }
    }

    private MyFragment myFragment;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // super.onBackPressed(); // comment to not back

        this.myFragment.onBackPressed(); // the onBackPressed method of Fragment is a custom method
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.` (in `onBackPressed()`) is rather of no use as `this` is default scope

Comment: The `this` refer to `MainActivity` scope @MarcinOrlowski.

Comment: Which us your scope anyway.

Comment: Just to be more formally @MarcinOrlowski.

Comment: No benefit. No point *in this case*. That's what I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, do not know if I understand your question, but if the idea and have control of direct backbutton in its fragment, and from it to perform some task of data persistence, you can add your fragment to control stack FragmentManager, the as follows.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

MyFragment mMyFragment = new MyFragment();

fm.beginTransaction()
    .add(mMyFragment, "mMyFragment")
    .addToBackStack( null )
    .commit();
```

**In the fragment you need to implement the interface OnBackStackChangedListener**

In Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnBackStackChangedListener {

    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
       //your code here
    }
}
```

**If you just keep the values**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    String valeu;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        if ( savedInstanceState != null ) {
            this.valeu = savedInstanceState.getString( "key" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState( final Bundle outState ) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );

        outState.putString( "key", "Your content" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while moving to front fragment, save the state of previous fragment using [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))
while moving back restore the state in onCreate() or onCreateView() in the previous fragment